# Remove spaces between numbers in a string in python

Tags: python, string

I want to remove all the whitespace between the numbers in a string in python. For example, if I have

```
my_string = "my phone number is 12 345 6789"
```

I want it to become

```
my_string = "my phone number is 123456789"
```

I thought I could do this for every number:

```
for i in range(10):
   my_string = my_string.replace(str(i)+" ",str(i))
```

But this isn't a smart and efficient solution. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just use regex! Now with support for variable number of spaces.

```
import re
my_string = "my phone number is 12 345 6789"
my_string = re.sub(r'(\d)\s+(\d)', r'\1\2', my_string)
```

Comment: Would you be able to expand that out to `r'(\d)(\s+)(\d)', r'\1\3'` to allow for more than one whitespace?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Does it even need to be a capturing group? Couldn't you just do `r'(\d)\s+(\d)', r'\1\2'`

Comment: this won't work for cases like `1 2 3 4 5 6 789`. It will change to `12 34 56 789`

Answer (score 9):

Just another regex way, using look-behind/ahead and directly just remove the space instead of also taking out the digits and putting them back in:

```
>>> re.sub('(?<=\d) (?=\d)', '', my_string)
'my phone number is 123456789'
```

I like it, but have to admit it's a bit longer and slower:

```
>>> timeit(lambda: re.sub('(?<=\d) (?=\d)', '', my_string))
1.991465161754789
>>> timeit(lambda: re.sub('(\d) (\d)', '$1$2', my_string))
1.82666541270698
```

Comment: Couldn't you just use 

`(?<=\d)\s+`

Comment: excellent answer- this is a quick improvement: `(?<=\d)\s+(?=\d)`