# Python how to remove whitespace between numbers

Tags: python, numbers, whitespace, tabular

I have a table with 4 columns with numbers, however in some columns there are whitespaces.

When I try to read the table, it produce the error:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float.

I solved this error removing the whitespace by hand, and it works, but I am wondering if Python has some solution in order to remove whitespace between numbers

My code to remove whitespace:

```
path = 'C:\Users\laboratorio\Desktop\waveletspy\prueba.txt'
path1 = 'C:\Users\laboratorio\Desktop\waveletspy\prueba1.txt'

clean_lines = []
with open(path, "r") as f:
    lines = (line.strip() for line in f.readlines() if len(line.strip()))     
    clean_lines = [l.strip() for l in lines if l.strip()]
    with open(path2, "w") as f:
      f.writelines('\n'.join(clean_lines))
```

The original  table:

```
 Y 2457620.83012      -0.433      0.004  
 Y 2457620.83100      -0.439       0.005  
 Y 2457620.83518      -0.459      0.004   
Y 2457620.83600      -0.470      0.005   
Y 2457620.83684      -0.498      0.004   
Y 2457620.83767      -0.480      0.005   
Y 2457620.83851      -0.490      0.005
```

Y 2457620.83934      -0.516      0.004

I want something like this

```
Y 2457620.83012 -0.433 0.004
Y 2457620.83100 -0.439 0.005
Y 2457620.83518 -0.459 0.004
Y 2457620.83600 -0.470 0.005
Y 2457620.83684 -0.498 0.004
Y 2457620.83767 -0.480 0.005
Y 2457620.83851 -0.490 0.005
Y 2457620.83934 -0.516 0.004
```

Comment: See if this works for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38640791/remove-spaces-between-numbers-in-a-string-in-python

Answer (score 0):

To have each word in each line separated by one space each:

#### Code:

```
clean_lines = [' '.join([w.strip() for w in l.strip().split()])
               for l in lines if l.strip()]
```

#### Test Code:

```
with open('file1', "r") as f:
    lines = (line.strip() for line in f.readlines() if len(line.strip()))
    clean_lines = [' '.join([w.strip() for w in l.strip().split()])
                   for l in lines if l.strip()]
    for line in clean_lines:
        print(line)
```

#### Results:

```
Y 2457620.83012 -0.433 0.004
Y 2457620.83100 -0.439 0.005
Y 2457620.83518 -0.459 0.004
Y 2457620.83600 -0.470 0.005
Y 2457620.83684 -0.498 0.004
Y 2457620.83767 -0.480 0.005
Y 2457620.83851 -0.490 0.005
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to do this. First replace all occurrences of multiple whitespace characters with a single space, then trim whitespace from the beginning and end of each line:

```
import re
with open(path, 'r') as f:
    result = re.sub(r'(^ | $)', '', re.sub(r'\w+', ' ', f.read()))
    print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using regular expressions. It will remove all the unusual whitespaces.

**Code:**

```
import re
path = 'C:\Users\laboratorio\Desktop\waveletspy\prueba.txt'
path1 = 'C:\Users\laboratorio\Desktop\waveletspy\prueba1.txt'

clean_lines = []
with open(path, "r") as f:
    lines = (line.strip() for line in f.readlines() if len(line.strip()))     
    clean_lines = [l.strip() for l in lines if l.strip()]
    with open(path2, "w") as f:
        for i in clean_lines:
            f.writelines(re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', str(i)))
            f.writelines('\n')
```

**Result:**

```
Y 2457620.83012 -0.433 0.004
Y 2457620.83100 -0.439 0.005
Y 2457620.83518 -0.459 0.004
Y 2457620.83600 -0.470 0.005
Y 2457620.83684 -0.498 0.004
Y 2457620.83767 -0.480 0.005
Y 2457620.83851 -0.490 0.005
```