# Remove space between two or more consecutive numbers in Java?

Tags: java, regex

How can i remove space between two or more consecutive numbers in a sentence using regex in Java?

For example,

Input string:

> Chân dung Mohamed Hilal, chủ nhân số điện thoại 0164 345 6164 có giá 2,2 triệu USD.

Expect output:

> Chân dung Mohamed Hilal, chủ nhân số điện thoại 01643456164 có giá 2,2 triệu USD.

Comment: Go to the below link will help you to find your answer. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38640791/remove-spaces-between-numbers-in-a-string-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38640791/remove-spaces-between-numbers-in-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may try this one

```
String inputString = "Chân dung Mohamed Hilal, chủ nhân số điện thoại 0164 345 6164 có giá 2,2 triệu USD."
String outputString = inputString.replaceAll("(?<=\\d) +(?=\\d)", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code,

```
    public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "Chân dung Mohamed Hilal, chủ nhân số điện thoại 0164 345 6164 có giá 2,2 triệu USD.";


        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d\\w+\\s)+");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println();

            String str = input.substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end()-1);

            String output = input.replace(str, str.replaceAll(" ", ""));
            System.out.println(output);
        }
    }
}
```