# How to remove whitespaces in numerical values in a text file in python?

Tags: python, regex, string, text, data-cleaning

I have a large text file as the output of OCR of several image documents, and it contains whitespaces in the middle of the parts of a number, e.g., "70 000 versus 100 000 NaCl", or "zones of the 8 42 hole". I want to remove these whitespaces and replace them with their original form: 70000, 100000 or 842. and I have another form of information like "wells 14 29a 3", which it's the correct form of the well ids and I do not want them to change or be concatenated. Can anyone help me with this, please?

for example for a sentence as the following:

```
'offset wells 14 29a 3, 14 286c 2 and 20 46 C and the value of 70 000 vs 100 000'
```

I want an output like this:

```
'offset wells 14 29a 3, 14 286c 2 and 20 46 C and the value of 70000 vs 100000'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove spaces between numbers in a string in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38640791/remove-spaces-between-numbers-in-a-string-in-python)

Comment: Thanks for the link. It removes the space in numbers but it removes the space for this kind of patterns too that they are an id with space. like "well 14 29a 3" will change to "well 1429a3"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.sub` with an expression that checks for either trailing whitespace or end-of-line as a match condition for the second digit component. Additionally, a custom replace function can be used to ensure that the match includes digit groups that would form a valid numerical value if the whitespace was replaced with a comma. This ensures that matches such as `20 46` do not become `2046`, since `20,46` is not a valid expression:

```
import re
s = 'offset wells 14 29a 3, 14 286c 2 and 20 46 C and the value of 70 000 vs 100 000'
def s_repl(s):
   f = ''.join(d:=re.findall('\d+', (_d:=s.group())))
   if all((int(f) >= 1000 and len(i) == 3) or (len(i) == len(f) - 1) for i in d[1:]):
      return ''.join(re.split('(?<=\d)\s(?=\d)', _d))
   return _d
   
new_s = re.sub('(?:\s|^)\d+\s\d+(?:\s|$)', s_repl, s)
```

Output:

```
'offset wells 14 29a 3, 14 286c 2 and 20 46 C and the value of 70000 vs 100000'
```