# How to remove white space between digit in string sentences python

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, nlp, python-re

I have sentences.

```
Sent = [“my contact number is 011 45 5554”,”my new contact number 034 543 4543”]
```

I need it to be like this:

```
Sent = [“my contact number is 011455554”,”my new contact number 0345434543”]
```

Only remove whitespace between digits

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38640791/remove-spaces-between-numbers-in-a-string-in-python

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

regex = r"(\d+)\s(\d+)\s(\d*)"

text = "my contact number is 011 45 5554”,”my new contact number 034 543 4543"
text = re.sub(regex, "\\1\\2\\3", text)

print (text)
```